# Weird Bubble Sort Algorithm

Tags: sorting

This is not my first time learning bubble sort algorithm in class. In a previous class, we start comparing from the first element of the array (i) and the second element of the array (i+1). But, When I study bubble sort today from my current class lecture slide, it is kind of different from what I learned in the previous class (see attached photo). So, my question is both methods are same? Which way is better?

[Bubble sort (sorting from front)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQkIB.jpg)

Comment: Neither - Do a quick sort or a merge sort

Comment: In terms of time and space complexity, they are identical. The only difference is whether counter increments or decrements through the array.

Comment: I know merge sort and quick sort are better than bubble sort. But, at least I do need to understand every algorithm.